# how to update text file in realtime

Tags: php

I want to make a simple chat system. I tried the following code:

```
<?

     $msgfilename=$_COOKIE['msgcookie'];

    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['txtmsg'])){

            $type=$_POST['txtmsg'];

            echo $type;

            $mymsg=fopen($msgfilename,"a+")or die("unable to open file");

            $msg=$type."<br>"."\n";

            fwrite($mymsg,$msg);

            fclose($mymsg);

    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $myfile = fopen($msgfilename, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

    $file = file($msgfilename);

    for ($i = max(0, count($file)-25); $i < count($file); $i++) {

      echo $file[$i] . "\n";

    }

    fclose($myfile);

    echo '<form action="sendmsg.php" method="post" name="txtmsgf">';

    echo '<input type ="text" name="txtmsg" >';

    echo '<input type="submit" value="send">';

    ?>
```

When I enter a message and click the send button I can see the sent message. But other people can't see I sent the message without refreshing the webpage.

Comment: @Niklesh Please fix the entire post if you are going to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side programming language. That means that everything PHP does is not done on the "client" computer. PHP code runs on the server and only does something when a client is "requesting" to know how a certain webpage looks, and that also means a computer must refresh the webpage in order to see any changes.

There is a solution, but it does not lie in using PHP, but learning **Ajax** and/or **asp.net** or some other "client-side" language that can request partial webpage server-requests. I don't know if JavaScript has a way of doing this or if JS MUST be used in combination with the above suggestions.